# git svn command crashes in the middle of cloning svn repo. How to fix that?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a svn repo with following structure

```
ProjectX
 -> trunk
 -> tags
     -> 1.0.x
     -> 1.1.x
 -> branches
     -> 1.1.1
```

I am trying to use git svn to convert this repo into a git repo but git svn crashes in the middle with following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $resolved in scalar chomp at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1764.
Use of uninitialized value $resolved in scalar chomp at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1764.
error: there are still refs under 'refs/remotes/svn/tags'
fatal: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/svn/tags'.
update-ref -m r133452 refs/remotes/svn/tags 819b5012690ffe22208d5727ad26673e2670560e: command returned error: 128

command failed:
git svn fetch
```

I am not sure what's happening but it crashes right where it starts getting the tags which were done on the 1.1.x branch. How to fix this?

Comment: Are the using the most current git version? If not I would update and try again, maybe the problem disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Several suggestions:

1. Use `svnadmin verify` to check the data stored in the repository. It's possible that the `svn` repository has errors. If you can work with it using `svn` (the usual operations: checkout, update, commit) then the chance to have a damaged repository is very small but it doesn't hurt to check, just to be sure. If `svnadmin verify` reports errors or inconsistencies then... I don't know if/how you can fix it.
2. Use [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com) to do the conversion; it produces better results that `git svn`.
3. If `SubGit` does not suit your needs then install a recent version of `Git`. The version provided by Apple is always months behind the latest version. Either download and compile the most recent version or install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and use it to install a newer version of `Git`.